# Fetch photos to css grid - one photo one grid cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am exploring some stuff with CSS grid and fetching. And i do have a problem. I want to fetch data from server and put it to my CSS grid layout.
My Grid looks like this [Code pen grid example](https://codepen.io/shivetay/pen/KKNPRKK) and this looks good, but it is hardcoded in html.
When i put this as JS all is getting messed up.
I am trying something like this:

```js
class UI{
 constructor(){
  const thisUI = this;
  thisUI.photo = document.querySelector('#photo');
 }
showPhotos(data) {
    const thisUI = this;
    let output = '';

    for (let photo of data) {
      output += ' here I am puttiong my hmlt code where I am using 
            data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}" 
            in my <a> tag
            and
            <img
            data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 1"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
            ';
    }
    thisUI.photo.innerHTML = output;
  }
}
```

I am using such code for all my grid itmes from 1 to 8, but this is casuing that one image is beeing fechetd 8 times. So i have 8x8 `<div>` filled with 8 the same photos

```
<div class="gallery_container">
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--${photo.id}">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
          data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
            data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 1"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--2">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
             data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 2"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--3">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
             data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 3"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--4">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
            data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
               data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 4"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--5">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
             data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 5"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--6">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
            data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 6"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--7">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
           data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 7"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery_item gallery_item--8">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt gallery_item--icon"></i>
          </a>
          <a
            data-id="${photo.id}"
            href="${photo.url}"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
               data-id="${photo.id}"
              src="${photo.url}"
              alt="Gallery image 8"
              class="gallery__img"
            />
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      `;
```

HTML for JS function `showPhotos`

Comment: The `output` is putting a bunch of text in between each `img`. This might cause issues with CSS grid

Comment: Also, show us the actual HTML you're generating, not HTML interspersed with comments

Comment: added the html for js